# psql function: append one dimensional array to a two dimensional array using array_append

Tags: postgresql, array

I tried to append an one dimensional array to a two dimensional array using array_append in psql function. I defined `count_values` as output by `out count_values integer[][]`, `cout_value` as variable in declare section by `count_value integer[]`, and tried to use `count_values := array_append(count_values, count_value)`, but the error `function array_append(integer[], integer[]) does not exist` poped up.

```
            if ...
            else
                count_value:= array_append(count_value, 0);
            end if;
            index:= index + 1;
        end loop;
        
        count_values:= array_append(count_values, count_value);
    end loop;
...
```

Comment: "An array can also be constructed by using the functions array_prepend, array_append, or array_cat. The first two only support one-dimensional arrays, but array_cat supports multidimensional arrays. " (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/arrays.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=db83ca30180e59e684bdd8336db2e59a)

```
create function f() returns integer[][]
as $$
declare
    count_value integer[] = '{5,6}';
    count_values integer[][] = '{{1,2},{3,4}}';
begin
  return Array_cat(count_values,count_value);
end; $$
language plpgsql;
```

or, starting with an empty array,

```
create function f() returns integer[][]
as $$
declare
    count_value integer[] = '{5,6}';
    count_values integer[][] ;
    new_cvs integer[][];
begin
  if count_values is null
  then new_cvs = array_cat(ARRAY[]::integer[][],ARRAY[count_value]);
  else new_cvs = Array_cat(count_values,count_value);
  end if ;
  return new_cvs;
end; $$
language plpgsql;
```

see [another fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f82ef52ec2c836a58400cd99c30d3675)

Comment: The problem is that, my two dimensional array will be empty at first beginning, and psql seems could not recognize that it is two dimensional

Comment: Then there is the possibility of telling postgresql that your array is two dimensional.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Made the example a little smarter.

Comment: Am I wrong with the cursor statements?

Comment: Can we try solving one problem at a time?

Comment: without knowing that, I can not be sure that it works in my code

Comment: The dbfiddle you made shows no error.  It would also help describing what your code intends to do, eg. by adding detailed comments.  It is a good programming habit.